# Handling redirection when session timeout via ajax

Tags: php, ajax, session, codeigniter-3

I have a view function which only logged in user can see. When clicking the view button, it will send an ajax request to PHP function and return back the result which then be displayed in the html. The issue is, if the user idle for too long, when they suddenly come and click the view button again, the display (where the ajax response supposed to be displayed) will show the login page instead of the requested data.

It was because the PHP session has expired. I want to prompt an alert to tell them about this timeout session and redirect them to the login page instead but I don't know how to do that cause I tried to `console.log()` the PHP session and it's still showing all of the session. I am convinced that this is something like a memory or a flash cache (not very sure).

```
QuickView = (pc_no) =>{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: '<?= $ajax_url; ?>view-receipt/'+pc_no,
        data: { pc_no:pc_no },
        success: function(res){
            console.log(<?= json_encode($this->session->userLogged); ?>)
            <?php if($this->session->userLogged){ ?>
                $('#receipt-inline-view').html(res);
            <?php } else { ?>
                if(alert('Your session has expired. Please re-login.')){
                    window.location.href = '<?= base_url(); ?>';
                }
            <?php } ?>
        }
    })
}
```

Based on the code above, the user session will be stored in `$this->session->userLogged`. After PHP timeout, it should be cleared. But from console at ajax there, it's still showing the session even after it gets cleared up. Hence, the redirection also cannot be triggered.

Comment: It looks like you're echoing the PHP session into the JavaScript. This will happen on page load, so if the user has a session at that time, it will forever be written into your JS. Regardless of what happens during the ajax event later, you already told it there's a session.

You could check the user session in the `view-receipt` PHP script, and return something to inform the JS that the session has expired. You would then check this in the ajax response and redirect if there's no session.

Comment: anything `<?php` is serverside so is only rendered once. utilise `error` in the ajax call and send a 401 status if not signed in rather then a login page dom, then you can pick it up in the error callback and show your message

Comment: @LawrenceCherone so if I have a lot pages doing ajax request, then I have to write the script redirection function to every page as well?

Comment: you could and should handle errors in all ajax calls. you could abstract out the main ajax part and setup your calls like `QuickView = pc_no) => ajax.get('<?= $ajax_url; ?>view-receipt/' + pc_no, data => {}, err => {})`

Comment: for example: https://playcode.io/643782/ hope it helps